# Can you lose a Harvester or Grustrag 3 Mark?

Tags: warframe

I am currently trying to collect Detonite Injectors for the Ogris. I see Invasion with lots of them (3 at a time), but I do not want to lose my G3 mark (seeing that I must work for the Grineer). Will I keep or lose it if I help them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get to keep your marks. =)

Answer (score 2):

You will never lose your marks, you can only "consume" marks if they appear during a mission.

Comment: This is the more correct answer.  You can't lose your marks through support.  You can be marked by all three enemies at once.  Being attacked by them will "consume" the mark.